# How to create an additional command prompt in Windows Server 2012?

Tags: command-line, windows-server-2012

I already have an active command prompt running in Windows Server 2012. I want to create an additional command prompt so I can run something else in that prompt.

If I click on 'Command Prompt' icon in the Apps tiles, it will only send the focus to the existing command prompt.

I can use 'Run...' in the Task Manager to create new one eventually.

My questions:

1) Why the Windows Server 2012 behaves this way?

2) Is there any way I can create a new command prompt via the Windows 8 style GUI alone?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When clicking, use the middle mouse button or hold down <kbd>Shift</kbd>. This also works directly on the taskbar, by the way.

As for why, probably because "Apps". You'd expect to return to where you left.

Answer (score 3):

Why not just run `start cmd` in the existing prompt?

This also gives you the same working directory as the existing prompt so may or may not save you some work.

Comment: It works but it does not quite fit my situation: I do not want to ctrl-c an active job in the original DOS prompt in order to run 'start cmd'. Thanks and have an upvote.

Comment: @AnthonyKong - cheers, it wasn't clear that the existing prompt was actually busy at the time (it may have been "I want to open a new command prompt so I can give it a long running job to do and then carry on working in the existing prompt") so I thought it was worth adding as an option.